# SBATCH -n and srun -np

Tags: mpi, slurm

In the sbatch script below, does "np" (48) take precedence over "ntasks" or only 24 tasks are used to run. In other words, what happens when "np" is greater than "ntasks" or "np" is equal to "ntasks * N"

```
#SBATCH --ntasks 24
#SBATCH -N 2
mpirun -np 48 ./run
```

Comment: Print out the slurm environment variables. You'll see that the hostlist is 24 items long, so if you create 48 processes, it will use each location in the hostlist twice. Depending on your core count that may lead to a loss of efficiency.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout thank you. I was wondering two things: (i) does it give wrong results or (ii) does it wait for the first 24 to finish before starting the next 24?

Comment: It will never give wrong results: it may just get slower. Or at least not faster. And no, all process run at the same time, but with more processes than cores Unix will time slice them.

Answer (score 1):

Print out the slurm environment variables. You'll see that the hostlist is 24 items long, so if you create 48 processes, it will use each location in the hostlist twice. Depending on your core count that may lead to a loss of efficiency: all process run at the same time, but if you have more processes than cores, Unix will time-slice them.